# Draw coastlines on the plots from data by basemap, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have tried to solve this problem considering other people's example. However, I still coulnd't get the result which I wanted. The results which I get were no coastlines or no coastline and no data plot (I used pcolor)

The data which I used was netcdf file of temperature through the area of interest. Because there is no boundaries info in the data itself, I would like to draw the coastlines over this figure.
The my code is as below:

```
Temp_plt =  Temp[18,:,:]
Lon_plt = Lon[18,:,:]
Lat_plt = Lat[18,:,:]
lons       = Lon_plt[0]
lats       = Lat_plt[0]
lat_min = min(lats)
lat_max = max(lats)
lon_min = min(lons)
lon_max = max(lons)
Temp_c = Temp_plt-273.15
m = Basemap(
        projection = 'merc',
        llcrnrlat=lat_min, urcrnrlat=lat_max,
        llcrnrlon=lon_min, urcrnrlon=lon_max,
        resolution='h', area_thresh=0.01
    )

m.drawcoastlines()
lon, lat= m.makegrid(Temp_plt.shape[1],Temp_plt.shape[0])
x1, y1 = m(lon,lat)
myPLT = m.pcolor(x1,y1,Temp_c)
```

Because my Longitude (Lon_plt) and Latitude (Lat_plt) were 2 d array, I have just tried those values for pcolor instead of x1 and y1 from makegrid. However, at that time, I couldn't see any coastlines, but temperature pcolor plot only. From the code above, I only could see red color all over the plot.

Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Thank you,

Isaac

Comment: I think the problem in your current code is that you're not constructing your coordinate grid properly. `Temp_plt.shape` will give you shape of the array, not the actual coordinates. So using `Lon_plt` and `Lat_plt` is the way to go. But before using them in `pcolor` you have to convert them from lat/lon to map coordinates: `x1, y1 = m(Lon_plt, Lat_plt)`. Did you try that?

Comment: Thank you abudis, actually I found my problem. That was just due to oreder between pcolor and m.drawcoastline. drawcoastline should be after pcolor. Thank you again for yout time and help.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment, the drawcoastlines() function should be called after the pcolor() function, so that the lines overlay the coloring, instead of vice-versa.